# I don't get why my question needs an edit

Tags: discussion, editing

This is the second time that someone edits my [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/369111/my-wlan-connection-is-hidden-even-broadcast-is-on).

What's wrong with it? It is short, output from the terminal is formatted. It is vexing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your version loses the line breaks, which makes it much harder to read than the edited versions.

Compare your version:

[image: Bahamat’s rendered version]

with this edited version:

[image: another rendered version]

Comment: Maybe, because I format my code not over your editor. I format as in a comment. Is this different?.

Comment: Yes, compare how the various edits are rendered.

Comment: Okay, the I will be more intentive .

Comment: @Bahamut more importantly, please don't take edits personally.  I am an elected moderator and 4th user by rep here and my posts are edited just like anyone else's. Your question is not your own, it belongs to the site and anyone has the right to edit it. That's a very big part of hoe the SE sites work. If you object to your posts being edited, then you won't have a goof time here. *Everyone's* posts are edited.